# Parsing a Json file with Gson 2.3.1

Tags: java, json, geolocation, gson

Having this json file to parse with GSON library

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"type":"Feature","properties":{"qualityScore":72,"formattedAddress":"Rue du Commerce; 4100 Seraing; Belgium","address":"rue du commerce","name":"rue du commerce"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[5.50852,50.612572]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"qualityScore":72,"formattedAddress":"Rue du Commerce; 4219 Meeffe; Belgium","address":"rue du commerce","name":"rue du commerce"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[5.01752,50.606201]}},{}]}
```

So this is one og the beans I've created to populate it from the Json file

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class Address {

    @Expose
    private String type;

    @Expose
    private List<GeolocationFeature> features = new ArrayList<GeolocationFeature>();

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<GeolocationFeature> getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures(List<GeolocationFeature> features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address [type=" + type + ", features=" + features
                + "]";
    }
}
```

Then when I try to parse it with Gson:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Address>>() {}.getType();
gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```

I've got this strange error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to parse an JSON object into a List.

The List is represented by the "features" property in the JSON object you are receiving. You can create a wrapper class with the same structure as your JSON response and then use GSON to parse it.

```
public class AddressWrapper {

    private String type;
    private List<Address> addresses;

    // getters and setters, etc...
}
```

Then you can parse it with GSON:

```
AddressWrapper addressWrapper = gson.fromJson(jsonString, AddressWrapper.class);
```

And access the addresses:

```
List<Address> addresses = addressWrapper.getAddresses();
```

Or, alternatively, you can create a custom parsing logic and use it to extract to content of the "features" property of the main JSON object and parse it to a List. You can consult the GSON documentation regarding Desearializers to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have it:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
gson.fromJson(jsonString, Address.class);
```